# How to convert byte[] from dtb to document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have byte[] from database that was previously .docx. Now i want to get this .docx back and work with it using Interop.Word. I followed many tutorials how to do that but always ended up with: File appears to be corrupted. 
What have i tried:

1.

```
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, fileBytes);
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(tmpFile);
```

2.

```
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(tmpFile);
fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Temporary;
File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, fileBytes);
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(tmpFile);
```

3.

```
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
string newPath = tmpFile.Replace(".tmp", ".docx");
File.Move(tmpFile, newPath);
File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, fileBytes);
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(newPath);
```

Everyone seems to do this and it works for them but not for me.

Comment: Seems that 3rd sample should work. Are you sure that there is correct `docx` file in the database? Try to download it (like your sample 1 does) and rename to `*.zip`. You can check the archive integrity to ensure that file was not broken.

Comment: 3rd sample should work. May be you can use full reference as `var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();`. What error do you get?